# Python Virtual Environment behaviour inside a Conda environment: Python Interpreter Choice

Tags: python, bash, numpy, module, conda

I am using a Conda environment for a program in order to configure the packages etc all correctly. However, I have trouble running the program without making any changes, as it seems to be the environment is not choosing the correct interpreter.

My conda yaml file is the following:

```
name: nmrfilter
channels:
  - rdkit
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - anaconda
  - rdkit
  - pytorch=1.4
  - torchvision
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - seaborn
  - scikit-learn
  - pyarrow
  - numba
  - click
  - pip
  - ipywidgets
  - pip:
    - python-igraph
    - louvain
    - ruffus
    - tqdm
    - networkx
    - tensorflow-cpu
    - tensorboardX
    - cirpy    
    - pubchempy
```

It should configure all of the python commands to use the Python3.7 installed by conda. However, when using a Python Virtual Environment inside the conda environment, I have reached unexplainable behaviour. My requirements.txt, from which a python venv is created, is the following:

```
numpy==1.24
scipy
pandas
rdkit
click
cirpy
scikit-learn
matplotlib
python-igraph
pubchempy
numba
torch
tqdm
igraph
louvain
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the directory path where the shell script is located
script_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# Check if the virtual environment already exists in the script's directory
if [ -f "$script_dir/nmrfilter_env/bin/activate" ]; then
    echo "NMRfilter_env already exists. Activating..."
    source "$script_dir/nmrfilter_env/bin/activate"
else
    echo "Creating virtual environment in $script_dir/nmrfilter_env..."
    python3 -m venv "$script_dir/nmrfilter_env"
    source "$script_dir/nmrfilter_env/bin/activate"

    echo "Installing the requirements..."
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

    echo "Installing Jupyter Notebook..."
    python -m pip install jupyter
fi

echo "Virtual environment activated."
echo "PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH"
echo "Python executable: $(which python)"
echo "Python3 executable: $(which python3)"
echo "PIP executable: $(which pip)"
echo "Python version: $(python --version)"
echo "PIP version: $(pip --version)"
echo "Pip packages in virtual environment:"
pip list | grep numpy



#start the processing
python3 nmrfilter.py $1

...
...

python3 nmrfilter2.py $1
```

When this script is run (for the first time, meaning creating the python virtual env), the following output is produced:

```
Virtual environment activated.
PYTHONPATH: 
Python executable: /home/karl/nmrfilterv15/nmrfilter_env/bin/python
Python3 executable: /home/karl/nmrfilterv15/nmrfilter_env/bin/python3
PIP executable: /home/karl/nmrfilterv15/nmrfilter_env/bin/pip
Python version: Python 3.7.16
PIP version: pip 22.0.4 from /home/karl/nmrfilterv15/nmrfilter_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Pip packages in virtual environment:


Simulating spectra for your compounds...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmrfilter2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from clustering import *
  File "/home/karl/nmrfilter/clustering.py", line 2, in <module>
    from numpy import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I am confused to as in how does it manage to pick an interpreter that does not have numpy installed, though my python venv and conda "nmrfilter" env both have numpy installed. What confuses me more is the script seems to be picking the python virtual environment interpreter as indicated, yet for some reason it does not include numpy in its pip list?

Overall, the packages from requirements.txt do not make it inside the pip list when run, tried with python3 -m pip list and python -m pip list.

Yet, when I run this purely with conda deactivated, everything gets installed and used correctly.

FYI, I know how to fix the issue (removing the python virtual in altogether as it is redundant), however, I'd like some explanations of its behaviour.

Comment: Your output doesn't include *anything* from the `if` statement that either creates or reactivates your virtual environment, so it's not clear if `pip install` ever executed.

Comment: The question overall I find confusing. A conda environment IS a virtual environment. Why do you want to use a virtual environment (venv) in a virtual environment (conda)? Unless you have specific reasons to do so, I would advise you to use conda OR venv, but not venv inside conda.

Comment: @topsail I know what conda is and what Python virtual environments are. I will remove the python venv altogether. I'm just looking to understanding the behaviour.

Comment: @chepner
Hey, the block gets executed. Currently debugged it to the error of numpy version 1.24 produces a ERROR: No matching distribution found error, which comes from the fact that conda installs Python 3.7. My bad, closing the question.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible, since the problem was with an undisclosed failure to properly create the virtual environment in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Answered my own question due to the issue being in package version discrepancies

Comment: Unrelated, you should probably try to move on from Python 3.7 sooner rather than later. It's been out of support for about 6 months now, and even 3.8 only has about 6 months of support left.

Comment: @chepner

Yup, actually on updating it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Error has been found - Conda nmrfilter environment installs Python 3.7, so when it is creating the virtual environment from requirements.txt, numpy=1.24 is unavailable since it requires Python >=3.8, therefore creating the error.